# Merge dataframes and fill gaps with duplicated columns and corresponding dates

Tags: r, merge, reshape, reduce

I have **three dataframes (df1, df2 and df3)**. I would like to merge them and also, fill each others gaps. For example: df1 contains USA data from 1990 to 1993 and df2 from 1994 to 1999. When I merge them using **reduce function**, I get duplicate data (USA.x, USA.y) instead of just USA with all consecutive dates and values.

I did as follows:

```
df1 <- data.frame(
  stringsAsFactors = FALSE, 
  Date = c("01/01/1990", "01/01/1991", 
           "01/01/1992", "01/01/1993", "01/01/1994", "01/01/1995"), 
  USA = c(1, 4, 2, 1, NA, NA), 
  FRANCE = c(4, 4, 2, 5, NA, NA), 
  ITALY = c(1, 4, 5, 2, NA, NA))

df2 <-data.frame(
  stringsAsFactors = FALSE, 
  Date = c("01/01/1994", "01/01/1995", 
           "01/01/1996", "01/01/1997", "01/01/1998", "01/01/1999"), 
  USA = c(3, 3, 1, 4, 3, 1), 
  FRANCE = c(2, 5, 2, 5, 5, 1), 
  MEXICO = c(4, 1, 4, 3, NA, NA))

df3 <- data.frame(
  stringsAsFactors = FALSE, 
  Date = c("01/01/1998", "01/01/1999", 
           "01/01/2000", "01/01/2001", "01/01/2002", "01/01/2003"), 
  MEXICO = c(3, 3, 5, 4, 2, 3), 
  BELGIUM = c(4, 2, 1, 4, 5, 1))


df_list <- list(df1, df2, df3)
```

***Option 1***

```
dfall1 <- Reduce(function(x, y) merge(x, y, all=TRUE), df_list, accumulate=FALSE)
View(dfall1)
```

***Results dfall1***

It integrates columns according to duplicated names but it duplicates the dates. There will be only one column for each contry but 2 rows of the same date: one with NA, the other with a value from another data frame.

***Option 2***

```
dfall2 <- Reduce(function(x, y) merge(x, y, all=TRUE, by = "Date"), df_list, accumulate=FALSE)
View(dfall2)
```

***Results dfall2***

Date rows are not repeated by column names will be renamed as .x and .y.

***Question***
How can I avoid duplicated row and columns. I wish for all data to be integrated according to their column name and corresponding dates

**I would like to end up with the following:**

[image: desired resuts]

Any help would be truly appreciated. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Reshaping, e.g. using `reshape2` package. First, reshape into long format, next `rbind` and `na.omit`, finally reshape wide.

```
> lapply(df_list, reshape2:::melt.data.frame, id.vars='Date') |> 
+   do.call(what='rbind') |> na.omit() |> reshape2::dcast(Date ~ variable) 
         Date USA FRANCE ITALY MEXICO BELGIUM
1  01/01/1990   1      4     1     NA      NA
2  01/01/1991   4      4     4     NA      NA
3  01/01/1992   2      2     5     NA      NA
4  01/01/1993   1      5     2     NA      NA
5  01/01/1994   3      2    NA      4      NA
6  01/01/1995   3      5    NA      1      NA
7  01/01/1996   1      2    NA      4      NA
8  01/01/1997   4      5    NA      3      NA
9  01/01/1998   3      5    NA      3       4
10 01/01/1999   1      1    NA      3       2
11 01/01/2000  NA     NA    NA      5       1
12 01/01/2001  NA     NA    NA      4       4
13 01/01/2002  NA     NA    NA      2       5
14 01/01/2003  NA     NA    NA      3       1
```

---

*Data:*

```
> dput(df_list)
list(structure(list(Date = c("01/01/1990", "01/01/1991", "01/01/1992", 
"01/01/1993", "01/01/1994", "01/01/1995"), USA = c(1, 4, 2, 1, 
NA, NA), FRANCE = c(4, 4, 2, 5, NA, NA), ITALY = c(1, 4, 5, 2, 
NA, NA)), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, -6L)), structure(list(
    Date = c("01/01/1994", "01/01/1995", "01/01/1996", "01/01/1997", 
    "01/01/1998", "01/01/1999"), USA = c(3, 3, 1, 4, 3, 1), FRANCE = c(2, 
    5, 2, 5, 5, 1), MEXICO = c(4, 1, 4, 3, NA, NA)), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, 
-6L)), structure(list(Date = c("01/01/1998", "01/01/1999", "01/01/2000", 
"01/01/2001", "01/01/2002", "01/01/2003"), MEXICO = c(3, 3, 5, 
4, 2, 3), BELGIUM = c(4, 2, 1, 4, 5, 1)), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, 
-6L)))
```

Comment: Thank you. I was getting errors so i just changed the pivot as follows: lapply(df_list, reshape2:::melt.data.frame, id.vars='Date')  %>% 
do.call(what='rbind') |> na.omit() |> reshape2::dcast(Date ~ variable)

Comment: @Drop You probably included the "+" which isn't code but the line indicator from the  console. Don't mix magrittr pipes  `%>%` with base pipes `|>`.

Comment: in dcast function I added "fun.aggregate = mean" for when values overlap, it takes the mean. Is not the case of this example but I applied it to a larger dataset, in case someone is running with the same problem: ```lapply(df_list, reshape2:::melt.data.frame, id.vars='Date') |>
  do.call(what='rbind') |> na.omit()|> reshape2::dcast(Date ~ variable, fun.aggregate = mean) ```

Comment: @Drop you could try a `|> unique()` right after the `na.omit` to remove duplicates which might be more efficient than calculating means.

Comment: Amazing. Thanks a lot.